# Select the second row value occurs,overwrite the first row value

Tags: sql, sql-server, mysqli

```
S.No   Name     Organization    
 1     Jhon       XXXx    
 2                zzzz
```

I want the result as John organization as zzzz

while select the table against 'Jhon' i want the organization table return value should be ZZZZ.I should overwrite the old organization.

Comment: Can you please clarify your question. It is not at all clear what you are asking. Maybe you could also show what you have tried.

Comment: I have wrote the second wrote is not equal to empty overwrite the second row value with the first row.. In this case I don't know to write the sql select query

Comment: At the very least, you can show the schema, and some sample data. I wouldn't even know where to begin guessing at what you are asking, without those.

Comment: If I write the query select organisation where name ='john'. I want zzzz as the organisation

Comment: It's not clear whether you wish to overwrite the a null value name from the immediately non null name OR overwrite organization from the next row where the name is null.

Comment: With all the suggestions to `UPDATE`, let's hope this isn't a production database.

Answer (score 1):

```
drop table t
go
create table t (id int, name varchar(10), organisation varchar(10))
go
truncate table t
insert into t values
(1,'n1','o1'),(2,null,'o2'),(3, null, 'o3'),(4,'n2','o4'),(5,null,'o5')
```

To overwrite null names with the previous non null name then using a correlated sub query to find the previous name would look like this

```
select t.id,
(select t2.name from t t2 where t2.name is not null and t2.id = (select max(id) from t t3 where t3.name is not null and t3.id < t.id)) name, 
t.organisation 
from t
where name is null

result
id          name       organisation
----------- ---------- ------------
2           n1         o2
3           n1         o3
5           n2         o5

(3 row(s) affected)
```

Conversely to find the next organisation

```
select t.id,t.name,
(select t2.organisation from t t2 where t2.name is null and t2.id = (select min(id) from t t3 where t3.name is null and t3.id > t.id)) organisation 
from t
where name is not null

Result
id          name       organisation
----------- ---------- ------------
1           n1         o2
4           n2         o5

(2 row(s) affected)
```

BOTH outcomes meet your requirement (and are of course entirely different)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want ??

```
   update<tablename>
    set Name='JHON'
    where name is null
```

Comment: I want the organization name as zzzz against John

Comment: This will do exactly  what you want.

Comment: update<tablename>
    set Name='JOHN'
    where Organization='zzzz'

Comment: Recommending an `UPDATE`, when the OP asked about selecting values from a table, is not a good approach. It is not clear what the OP wants, so "this will do exactly what you want" is a questionable statement.

Answer (score 0):

A simple sql case should help you determine whether the name is jhon and then set the appropriate organization as 'zzzz', if name is not 'Jhon' then the default organization will be assigned

```
select 
  name, 
  [organization] = case 
                     when name = 'Jhon' then 'zzzz' 
                     else organization 
                   end
from tablename
```

Comment: I will have only two rows first row values are default and the second rows values will be variable if in the second row values are there it should overwrite the first row value